# Issues with git hooks permissions on Windows

Tags: windows, git, permissions, githooks

I have a bare git repository running on a Windows machine, and I am trying to have it run a post-receive hook. I have the following in the hooks/post-receive file

```
cmd //c "activate <some-env> && do-something"
```

which works nicely if it is run manually from Git Bash. However, it doesn't run after a commit is pushed.

The file's permissions, as obtained from Git Bash by doing `ls -lh`, are `644`. This may be the issue, but `chmod +x <file>` has no effect. Neither does `git update-index --chmod=+x <file>`, as suggested elsewhere - this results in `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree` (I guess this is not meant for a bare repository). The permisions in the sample hooks are well set, but if I do `echo <my-command> > some-hook.sample` the execute permissions are lost. This is also the case if I modify the file using e.g. Notepad++.

How does one change the execute permissions in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Right-click the file in the file explorer and select properties(I'm not sure if it's the word in English. The shortcut on the menu is R), click the Git tab, check `Executable(+x)`. I tried it on Windows 10.

Comment: I don't have such a tab (then again I'm using Win7 because that's what I have at work, so that may be why).

Comment: I found a workaround for my particular case, but the question stands for the general case, so I'll leave it up for now.